# audit: type=1400, apparmor='denied'

Tags: linux-kernel, driver, audit, apparmor, dmesg

I have written a program .c and Makefile. Makefile created a file .ko, afer this I used the next commands:

sudo insmod filename.ko
sudo sysctl kernel.dmesg_restrict=0
dmesg | tail

As result, I recieved such strings:

[169396.221688] audit: type=1400 audit(1697726842.148:30133473): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" class="ptrace" profile="snap.python-ai-toolkit.jupyter" pid=1133 comm="python3" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
[169396.221693] audit: type=1400 audit(1697726842.148:30133474): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" class="ptrace" profile="snap.python-ai-toolkit.jupyter" pid=1133 comm="python3" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
[169396.221695] audit: type=1400 audit(1697726842.148:30133475): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" class="ptrace" profile="snap.python-ai-toolkit.jupyter" pid=1133 comm="python3" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
[169396.221706] audit: type=1400 audit(1697726842.148:30133476): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" class="ptrace" profile="snap.python-ai-toolkit.jupyter" pid=1133 comm="python3" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
[169396.221745] audit: type=1400 audit(1697726842.148:30133477): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" class="ptrace" profile="snap.python-ai-toolkit.jupyter" pid=1133 comm="python3" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="/usr/sbin/cupsd"
[169396.221760] audit: type=1400 audit(1697726842.148:30133478): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" class="ptrace" profile="snap.python-ai-toolkit.jupyter" pid=1133 comm="python3" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="/usr/sbin/cups-browsed"
[169396.221881] audit: type=1400 audit(1697726842.148:30133479): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" class="ptrace" profile="snap.python-ai-toolkit.jupyter" pid=1133 comm="python3" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
[169396.221890] audit: type=1400 audit(1697726842.148:30133480): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" class="ptrace" profile="snap.python-ai-toolkit.jupyter" pid=1133 comm="python3" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
[169396.221903] audit: type=1400 audit(1697726842.148:30133481): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" class="ptrace" profile="snap.python-ai-toolkit.jupyter" pid=1133 comm="python3" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
[169396.221917] audit: type=1400 audit(1697726842.148:30133482): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" class="ptrace" profile="snap.python-ai-toolkit.jupyter" pid=1133 comm="python3" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"

My code is:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>

/* Meta Information */
MODULE_LICENSE("GPU");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Johannes 4 GNU/Linux");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("A hello world LKM");

/**
 * @brief This function is called, when the module is loaded into the kernel
**/
static int __init ModuleInit(void) {
        printk("Hello, Kernel!\n");
        return 0;
}

/**
 * @brief This function is called, when the module is removed from the kernel
 * */
static void __exit ModuleExit(void) {
    printk("Goodbye, Kernel\n");
    }

module_init(ModuleInit);
module_exit(ModuleExit);
```

And Makefile:

```
obj-m += mymodule.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

I didn't manage fix those. I have Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS. What should I do?

I tried that my program responds the command:
dmesg | tail

Comment: Probably, the error is originated from the kernel module which you write. You don't show the code of your module, so we cannot verify that.

Comment: I've edited. I've added codes.

Comment: Are you sure that given log is emitted **only** when you have your module loaded into the kernel? For me it looks like given audit events are unrelated to your module at all. About fixing these messages you are better to ask on [ubuntu.se].

Comment: Thank you, I have asked on 'Ask Ubuntu'